# Difference between property defining (with and without {get; set;})

Tags: c#, properties, definition

I have this

```
public int CityId { get; set; }
```

and

```
public int CityId;
```

If I use first - it works in EF code first while the second - doesn't. But if I definte `{get; set;}` and do nothing else, what is the exact difference between a simple definition? I understand that I can add some additional/customized code to `{get; set;}` layout, but doesn't it work exactly the same if without `{get; set;}`?

Comment: The latter is a field, the former is a property.

Comment: Long term, properties provide additional benefits (like the ability to declare as `virtual`, `abstract`, or in interfaces). Sometimes significantly, even though the calling/usage code may be identical (assigning/getting values to/from _look_ like the same C# syntax), it is a breaking change to switch. Third-parties leveraging your code _must_ recompile their code to match the change. If they simply replace the compiled DLLs without recompiling, they will receive runtime errors.

Comment: I can't speak for EF, but my past experience with NHibernate _required_ the members to be properties (maybe even virtual? Maybe just for lazily-loading bags/collections) because it would compile _subclasses_ on-the-fly which would override/implement the property behaviour to lazily load data from the database. Such behaviour is (likely) _impossible_ with fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int CityId;
```

This is a field.

```
public int CityId { get; set; }
```

This is a property, and the compiler will generate a private field for you automatically to back the property.

They are two different things.  A property provides a getter, a setter, or both.  The "get" and "set" operations on properties are compiled as method calls.

A field is just an exposed variable.  It is generally considered bad practice for fields to be public.

Comment: `It is generally considered bad practice for properties to be public.` - did you mean variables instead of properties OR, if not, can you please explain why?

Comment: I meant fields, not properties.  That's the second obvious and terrible mistake I've made today in SO answers...

Comment: Don't worry :)) You were very helpful :))

Answer (score 2):

With this syntax:

```
public int CityId { get; set; }
```

you're actually creating an auto-implemented property and behind the scenes it gets translated to this:

```
private int _CityId;
public int CityId { 
    get
    {
        return _CityId;
    } 
    set
    {
        _CityId = value;
    }
}
```

This syntax:

```
public int CityId;
```

is just a field

Answer (score 1):

The difference you are looking for is called encapsulation.

[example](http://www.csharp-station.com/tutorials/lesson19.aspx)

In your example is not a big difference between the field and the property. The field got a better performance than the property because it doesn't need to call a method to access it. Anyway the disadvantages of a field is that everyone can access it and you (the class holding the field) don't have any control about it.

Comment: I think your answer explains my question as a comment on cdhowie's answer! Thanks!